# Any created file on mounted NFS has permissions Nobody

Tags: permissions, nfs

Been grappling with this for a few days and need some help, GOOGLE'in around hasnt yielded anything that worked as of yet. So here is the situation (apologies if I miss anything):

-There is a main system that works fine with many mounted HDs

-There are several side systems with their own processors that also mount the same HDs.  The side systems (nodes?) shares home directories with the main system

-I have sudo access to all systems so I can check whatever

-I have created users on both systems with same UIDs and groupIDs and affiliated groups (confirmed using id USERNAME and checking /etc/passwd and /etc/group on both systems [pasted below])

- Whenever I create something on the main system, all looks good
- Whenever I create something on the side system, group seems to work right, but user does not.

-2 other users of the systems have none of my problems (worked fine for the last 3 years for them).  I just joined the team and we cant get it to work right for me.

-Im told its nfs mounted though i'm less familiar with these things than one might prefer so I have no other details

-Below some stats:

USERNAME katz

UID 1019

sidesystem: UBUNTU 14.04
mainsystem: UBUNTU 12.02

```
katz@SIDESYSTEM:/home/katz$ cat /etc/passwd | grep katz
katz:x:1019:1019::/home/katz/:/bin/bash

katz@MAINSYSTEM:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep katz
katz:x:1019:1019:My Name,,,:/home/katz/:/bin/bash
```

then

```
katz@SIDESYSTEM:/home/katz$ ls -1l | grep bk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody katz          0 Jul 20 22:06 bk

katz@MAINSYSTEM:~$ pwd
/home/katz/
katz@MAINSYSTEM:~$ ls -1l | grep bk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 katz katz          0 Jul 20 22:06 bk
```

In reading other potential answers on this site, below are a few other potentially useful bits:

```
katz@SIDESYSTEM:/home/katz$ cat /etc/exports   [Some numbers replaced with Xs for privacy]
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/dataXX          XX.XX.X.XX(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/dataXX          XX.XX.X.XX(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
....etc.

katz@MAINSYSTEM:~$ cat /etc/exports
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/home           XX.XX.X.XX(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
...etc
```

Happy to add any other information others think would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You specified your share with NFSv3-style syntax.
When mounting on the client, try mounting with -o nfsvers=3

```
mount -t nfs 1.2.3.4:/home /home -o nfsvers=3
```

By default, NFSv4 is used which is kind of compatible with v3, so the mount succeeds, but the mapping of user ids and permissions is messed up. So either use NFSv4 server-side or force the client to use v3 using that option.

Comment: I will certainly try this when possible, but we have a bunch of jobs running on the machine that we can't kill for a week or two or three, otherwise we risk loosing a bunch of work.  Are there any temporary solutions that could allay this problem?    Very much appreciate your answer and your time.

Comment: None that I know of, while you're using the mountpoint. You can try mounting another share for testing purposes, maybe create one to see if it works.